# Mapping functions from the plot tools to the ax tools

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, handle

I've been using matplotlib for a while now, and the more I read the documentation, the more I get the feeling I'm supposed to be using ax tools instead of plt tools.  What I mean is, I could create a plot using the "old way"

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
y = x**2
plt.figure('my figure')
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Or I could do the same plot using the preferred "new way"

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(num='my figure')
ax.plot(x,y)
```

I get it that the second method is nicer since it gives me handles to the fig and ax.  However, there seems to be a whole bunch of functions which are easy to do using the first method and I can't figure out how to do using the second. For example, how do you do `plt.close()` or `plt.clf()`?  Has anyone put together a mapping from the "old method" of plotting to the "new method" of plotting?

I also find it hard to even ask questions about this, since there doesn't seem to be an agreed upon way to discuss these two different ways of plotting as separate from each other.

wanted to clear a figure and couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You just need to call `dir` on your figure or axes to know what they can do, or read the official documentation for those two objects. Things usually have the same name. `plt.close()` is `fig.close()`, `plt.clf()` is `fig.clear()`.

Comment: Things relating to the figure as a whole will be called from the figure. For example, closing, clearing (`clf` stands for clear figure), or saving. Things related to the axes are done with that object. For example, plotting, clearing the axes (`cla` for clearing the axes), creating a legend, or adding axes labels.